# Saving int to binary file in c

Tags: c, file, binary

I'm making a simple game for my programming class. And I'm having trouble saving the play to a binary file, it writes only the letter of the coordinate.

int number is just one number from 6 to 8.
char letter is just one letter from A to J.

I want the coordinate to appear on file like A1...

Does anybody knows how to fix it ?

Here's the function:

```
void makeLoad(FILE *f,char letter, int number){
    f = fopen("save.dat", "a+");
    if( f==NULL ) {
      printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro\n");
      return ; }
      printf("%c\n", letter );//debug purposes 
      printf("%d\n", number );//debug purposes 

    fwrite(&letter,sizeof(letter),1,f);
    fwrite(&number,sizeof(number),1,f);

    fclose(f);
  }
```

I'm expecting at the end to have a sequence of plays like A1B3C5
But i get only ABC ... the numbers are missing in between

Here's the full file if needed: http://pastebin.com/WzynZuaC

Comment: How big is the output file?  How do you examine its contents?  Are you expecting to find the number as text?

Comment: What did `fwrite` return?

Comment: I'm expecting at the end to have a sequence of plays like A1B3C5...

Comment: Also, why do you take `FILE *f` as a function argument when you don't use the value passed in anyway?  Why not just have a local `FILE *` variable in the function?

Comment: I checked the file afterward and i only get the sequence of letters like ABC. The numbers are missing

Comment: I pretend to use that file in other function to make  a load game later. That's why i use it as an argument

Comment: If you want to write human-readable text to the file, like 'A1', you should use `fprintf()` or something else that produces a textual representation of the data.  Your `fwrite()` call just writes the bytes that make up the value in memory... which is fine if you plan to load it into a similar variable with `fread()` later, but it's not readable text.

Comment: Try looking at the file in a hex editor and you may find that the data is there but doesn't display when you view it as text.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `'a+b'` instead of `'a+'` for the `fopen()` file mode, to use binary mode (for Windows, to prevent it from trying to convert line endings that might seem to be in the bytes of your integer).

Comment: Yup is that my bad :/ Thank you!

Comment: "expecting at the end to have a sequence of plays like A1B3C5 But i get only ABC"  --> Code does not show how only ABC is gotten.  Neither does the post explain how it was determined how only ABC was read.  Amend the code to show how the results are reported and only return ABC.  Else how does one know the write is at fault and not the reading?

Comment: You're writing the values as binary.  Characters will still be human-readable, but numbers will be written as raw data rather than characters.  You can convert the numbers to strings when writing them, or you can find another way to view your binary data.  Just understand that the number `1` and the character `'1'` have different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way you can fix it, as long as the number is only one digit:

```
char c = '0' + number;
fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,f);
```

What you were doing is writing the binary representation of your int into the file, which is not the same as the ASCII representation. For instance, the binary representation of the character '6' is 00110110, whereas the binary representation of the int 6 is 00000000000000000000000000000110. You're writing the latter into your file, when you want to write the former. Adding '0' to number adds 00110000, which gives the correct binary value after the implicit cast to a character.

The cleaner way to fix your code is to replace the fwrite calls with a single fprintf call, which does all the work for you:

```
fprintf(f, "%c%d", letter, number);
```